# How digital video is processed?

Tags: digital-logic, video, vga

I'm not sure if I'm using the right words, but I would like to learn how digital video works. I have a book that explains how VGA works and how to implement it on FPGA. I would like to know what kind of data the computer sends and how the monitor understands it and displays 1080p/720p resolution. Is there a book explaining that?

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in how digital video is sent there are a number of current standards which are relevant.  As you mention VGA it is worth focusing on digital signalling designed to work between device and screen, rather than broadcast standards.

Right now there are three standards for consumer devices and each has an excellent Wikipedia article: [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface), [HDMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) and [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).

These standards define the electrical connection, the physical connector and the encoding for the data sent & received.  Both HDMI and DisplayPort allow you to send more than just video information, for example audio or network data.

Compared to HDMI the DisplayPort standard is license free which might make it interesting if you were implementing a new device.  However it has little market share right now.

At the electrical level both DVI-D and HDMI use [TMDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition-minimized_differential_signaling) "links", using pairs of differential signals to send data.  DisplayPort uses [LVDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVDS) instead and calls each pair a "lane".

For encoding all three protocols use a form of [8b/10b encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding) to remove DC bias.

Similar to any other video implementation (including VGA) your sending device will need some form of screen buffer that contains the pixel data you wish to send.  For VGA you scan the whole screen in the correct time period ("refresh rate") and convert these to analogue signal levels.  For any digital video data you simply encode the data then send to the differential driver.

Your VGA book will discuss the horizontal & vertical synchronisation lines, the front and back porch etc.  For digital video these are replaced by a clock line with framing (the horizontal and vertical sync) embedded as digital symbols within the data.  HDMI has a little more overhead compared to DVI-D because some signalling information, such as "is there audio in this stream", is also encoded into the data.

All three digital standards described here also support signalling which provides the display with information about the resolution and capabilities of the sender.  [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) is the standard controlling this which uses [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C)  Whilst VGA does support I²C for HDMI I believe it is mandatory, which complicates any implementation.

It is conceivable to implement an entire digital video sender in a modern FPGA provided the following constraints are met:

- the device has enough RAM to store a screen buffer
- the clock speed is high enough to cope with the required refresh/signalling rate
- there are differential drivers available to you in the part

You could also use a dedicated part like the [Analog Devices ADV7511](http://www.analog.com/en/audiovideo-products/analoghdmidvi-interfaces/adv7511/products/product.html) which handles all of this if you feed the video data.

There are various projects online that implement DVI-D or HDMI in an FPGA.  These will likely be a good place to start but none that I have found are particularly complete and for a consumer device you would obviously need to pay the HDMI royalty fee.

Some useful reading:

- Hack A Day's article: [Moving an FPGA project from VGA to DVI-D](http://hackaday.com/2012/08/03/moving-an-fpga-project-from-vga-to-dvi-d/)
- Xilinx appnote: [Implementing a TMDS Video Interface in the 
  Spartan-6 FPGA](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp495_S6TMDS_Video_Interface.pdf)
- An [overview of DisplayPort](http://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ICCE-Presentation-on-VESA-DisplayPort.pdf) from VESA
- [Altera's DisplayPort core](http://www.altera.co.uk/technology/high_speed/protocols/displayport/pro-displayport.html) - read the documentation
- [Xilinx's DisplayPort LogiCORE](http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/EF-DI-DISPLAYPORT.htm)

Comment: Your comment is insanely informative!!! Thank you so much!